# Swift Array addObjects to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a `Swift` `Array` and I want to add all the objects inside to `NSMutableArray`

```
let stringName: String = "Something"
let stringNameSeperated = Array(logoName)
let mutableStringName: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: stringNameSeperated)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you wanted to archive, but if you just wanted a `Swift.Character` sequence array, here's a simpler way without even the `Array()` process: (Notice that the result was casted into `String`. If you want `Character`, you will have to modify the code a bit.)

```
let stringName: String = "Something"
let mutableStringName: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: map(stringName) { String($0) } )
```

And from my understanding, you no longer have to case between Swift Array and Objective-C Array, you can use them interchangeably. Also, you can pass a Swift Array to a parameter that expected to be NSArray without problem in Swift 1.x as well.

Comment: But it return an array inside of array... to access it I need to do mutableStringName[0] and there is the array, how can I fix that?